# How to find the type of a Scala expression

Tags: scala

Can I find out the type of an expression in Scala. This would be particuarly useful when debugging complex partial functions, implicit conversions, etc...

For example:

```
println(  typeOf( x+y ) )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish to print as you have specified then:

```
scala>  def manOf[T: Manifest](t: T): Manifest[T] = manifest[T]
manOf: [T](t: T)(implicit evidence$1: Manifest[T])Manifest[T]

scala> val x = List(1,2,3)
x: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> println(manOf(x))
scala.collection.immutable.List[Int]
```

If you are in repl mode then

```
scala> :type List(1,2,3)
List[Int]
```

Answer (score 5):

In the scala console, you can use `:type`:

```
:type x+y
```

At runtime (including in the console) you can do:

```
scala> import reflect.ClassTag
import reflect.ClassTag

scala> def exprType[T:ClassTag]( x: T ) = implicitly[ClassTag[T]]
exprType: [T](x: T)(implicit evidence$1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[T])scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]

scala> exprType( x+y)
res1: scala.reflect.ClassTag[String] = java.lang.String
```

exprType will return the `ClassTag` the parameter. Because ClassTag are not resilient to erasure, you might want to use a `TypeTag` instead (but this requires to have "scala-reflect.jar" in the classpath):

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._
def exprType[T:TypeTag]( x: T ) = implicitly[TypeTag[T]]
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that's what I'm looking for. So... like looks like types are not first class objects in scala. I could never write: exprType(x+y)==Int  (as you can in, say, Python)?

Comment: You can do `exprType( x+y ) == typeTag[Int]`

Comment: Sure, but Int is not a first class object.